# How to extract 3d mouse coordinate on mouse click in Matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, visualization

The 3D mouse coordinates shows in the status bar of matplotlib window. But does anybody know how to get these coordinates from the status bar or using any function of matplotlib.
[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9673338/1002176

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you get your data, but I use this when I want the x,y from a image. In callback(event) you need event.zdata to also print the z value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

def callback(event):
        print event.xdata, event.ydata, event.zdata


img = cv2.imread(file)


fig, ax = plt.subplots() 

fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('button_press_event', callback)
plt.imshow(img,'gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: no event.zdata but stackoverflow.com/a/9673338/1002176 works