# Matplotlib: ax.format_coord() in 3D trisurf plot - return (x,y,z) instead of (azimuth, elevation)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, mouseevent

I was trying to redo this already answered question [Matplotlib - plot_surface : get the x,y,z values written in the bottom right corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748184/matplotlib-plot-surface-get-the-x-y-z-values-written-in-the-bottom-right-cor?rq=1), but wasn't capable of getting the same result, as stated there. So, I have a code like:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement

#Handle the "onclick" event
def onclick(event):
    print('%s click: button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
          ('double' if event.dblclick else 'single', event.button,
           event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))
    print(gety(event.xdata, event.ydata))

#copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748184/matplotlib-plot-surface-get-the-x-y-z-values-written-in-the-bottom-right-cor?rq=1
def gety(x,y):
    s = ax.format_coord(x,y)
    print(s) #here it prints "azimuth=-60 deg, elevation=30deg"
    out = ""
    for i in range(s.find('y')+2,s.find('z')-2):
        out = out+s[i]
    return float(out)

#Read a PLY file and prepare it for display
plydata = PlyData.read("some.ply")
mesh = plydata.elements[0]
triangles_as_tuples = [(x[0], x[1], x[2]) for x in plydata['face'].data['vertex_indices']]
polymesh = np.array(triangles_as_tuples)

#Display the loaded triangular mesh in 3D plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(mesh.data['x'], mesh.data['y'], mesh.data['z'], triangles=polymesh, linewidth=0.2, antialiased=False)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

With this, the triangular surface is properly displayed (although slowly). I can see the (x,y,z) coordinates of the surface in the bottom right corner, while I hover over the plot. But when I try to get these coordinates with the click of mouse (through the connected event handler), the ax.format_coord(x,y) fction returns not a string of cartesian coordinates, but a string of "azimuth=-60 deg, elevation=30deg", no matter where in the plot I click, until the surface is rotated. Then it returns another values.  From this I suppose these are spherical coordinates of the current view, not the clicked point, from some reason...

Can someone find out, what am I doing wrong? How do I can get the cartesian coordinates on the surface?

FYI: This all is related to my previous question [Python: Graphic input in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883082/python-graphic-input-in-3d?noredirect=1#comment87581990_49883082), which was considered too broad and generic.

Comment: Getting a 3D coordinate from a 2D click event is anyways not very useful, is it? I mean a point in 2D is a complete line in 3D. Do you want to get that line equation out?

Comment: Please also see [mcve]. I mean why on earth are you showing some code noone can run?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for pointing out that the example code is not working. I have verified it and it should be functional now. Please, try it (with any standard PLY file in the same folder).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest You are right, the point in 2D is a line in the 3D, but it has only finite number of intersections with the surface. Usually only one or two. I want to pick the one, which is closest to the viewer. Well, the Matplotlib seems to be able to resolve this properly, as it displays the desired coordinates in the bottom right corner of the window.

Comment: Well if you consider the coordinates shown by matplotlib in the bottom corner to be useful, you may use the answer I provided below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mousebutton being pressed is the trigger for `ax.format_coord` to return the angular coordinates on a 3D plot instead of the cartesian ones. So an option is would be to let the `ax.format_coord` think that no button is pressed, in which case it would return the usual cartesian x,y,z coordinates as desired.

A bit of a hacky way to achieve this, even though you clicked the mousebutton, would be to set the `ax.button_pressed` (which stores the current mousebutton) to something unreasonable while calling that function.

```
def gety(x,y):
    # store the current mousebutton
    b = ax.button_pressed
    # set current mousebutton to something unreasonable
    ax.button_pressed = -1
    # get the coordinate string out
    s = ax.format_coord(x,y)
    # set the mousebutton back to its previous state
    ax.button_pressed = b
    return s
```

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest , it does work! Yet I have no idea why. Could you explain, why it is necessary to suppress the mousebutton event?

Comment: I tried to explain it a bit more in detail. Feel free to ask about what exactly is not clear if that doesn't help.